# installing psycopg in alpine docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile, psycopg2, docker-image

I have the following dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.12.0-alpine3.18

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apk update && \
    apk add --virtual build-deps gcc python3-dev musl-dev && \
    apk add postgresql-dev


COPY requirements ./requirements
RUN pip install -r ./requirements/local.txt

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8000
```

Here is my requirements.txt:

```
Django==4.2.7
psycopg==3.1.13
```

The following error occurs when the image is loaded:

```
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c pip install -r ./requirements/local.txt" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

I tried to install various dependencies in my dockerfile. But always the same error.

What dependencies do I need to add to my dockerfile for psycopg to install?
And also where can you read what dependencies you need to add and your dockerfile for certain libraries based on a certain image?

Comment: "process "/bin/sh -c pip install -r ./requirements/local.txt" did not complete successfully" This is not the root cause.  Pip error output is verbose and hard to read.  But you have to go back to that error message and pull out the root cause.  If you can't find it, post the entire error message here and we'll help you dig it out.

Comment: There are a couple of existing questions on this topic already, and you may see if one of these already answers your question.  For Python in particular, Debian-based images can use precompiled "wheel"-format Python packages, and you can often get much simpler images if you avoid an Alpine base.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be some inconsistencies in the paths used in your `Dockerfile`. Please try the following using your current `requirements.txt`:

```
FROM python:3.12.0-alpine3.18

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apk update && \
    apk add --virtual build-deps gcc python3-dev musl-dev && \
    apk add postgresql-dev

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8000
```

Below you can see the image builds successfully and you can load both packages in Python.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! But I already have everything working with the following dependencies:  `RUN apk add --no-cache gcc python3-dev libc-dev linux-headers`, `RUN apk add postgresql-client build-base postgresql-dev`